# Conditional routing based on Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, middleware

I need to call **different controller** for the same url based on a middleware. The url has to be the same, so redirecting in the middleware is not an option. The code below is sample, controllers for dozens for routes are already finished, so checking the session value there is not an option either.

Tried to create two different middleware (has/hasnt the session value), but the latter route group overwrites the previous anyway. Any clue? Maybe a different approach needed?

**route.php** looks like this:

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function () {

    // set of default routes
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'FirstController@index'))->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'FirstController@profile'))->middleware('admin');

    Route::group(array('middleware' => 'sessionhassomething'), function () {
        // set of the same routes like above but overwritten if middleware validates    
        Route::get('/', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'SecondController@index'))->middleware('admin');
        Route::get('/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'SecondController@profile'))->middleware('admin');
    });
});
```

SessionHasSomething **middleware**:

```
class sessionHasSomething {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(session()->has("something_i_need_to_be_set")) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // return what if not set, or ...?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only checking if `session()->has('something')`, it is possible to use **route closures** to add a condition within the route which needs to be dynamic.

Below is an example:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $controller = session()->has('something')) ? 'SecondController' : 'FirstController';
    app('app\Http\Controllers\' . $controller)->index();
});
```

`->index()` being the method within the controller class.

Comment: I really like this approach, however all the ~100 routes has to be moved to the middleware from the route.php. It seems a little off to me, but it could work.

Comment: Understandable, there may be another method which I find shortly.

Answer (score 0):

We almost have the same issue and here's what I did. (I didn't use middleware).

In my `blade.php`, I used `@if`, `@else` and `@endif`

```
<?php
   use App\Models\User;
   $check = User::all()->count();
?>
@if ($check == '0')
    // my html/php codes for admin
@else
    // my html/php codes for users
@endif
```

you can also do that in your controller, use `if`,`else`.

Comment: The problem is we have the blades and controllers are finished already so hundreds of conditions had to be made this way. I would like to avoid this.